# How to get current time in mongo aggregate?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

**I want to get the objects that have the time property greater than current time. How to get them?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
var date = moment().toDate()
    Model.aggregate([
{$match:{createdAt:{$gte: date}}}
])
```

Comment: I tried 
{$match:{createdAt:{$gte: moment().toDate()}}}
and it worked. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query if you want to query documents those have `time` property greater than current time

```
db.collection.find({"time" : { $gt : new Date() }});
```